# Bicep Template for Azure Automation Account. Azure Role assignment to Managed Identity problem

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-bicep

I have created a basic Bicep template to deploy Azure Automation Acount. It contains a Runbook with the Powershell script and the linked Schedule. So far so good. The problem is to assign the Azure Role (Owner, Contributor, Reader) to the Managed Identity of this AA. I have all the needed values but have no idea how to put them together. To assign Azure Role via Bicep Template you should get the principalId of your Managed Identity of this AA which is pretty easy:

```
resource autaccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2021-06-22'
**************************************************************************
output AutAccountPrincipalId string = autaccount.identity.principalId
```

My idea was to pass the value from this output to the parameter or variable and then use it in the next resource block. It turned out I can not pass the output as the parameter to the next resource block. Can someone assist me with this? The question is - how to use the value from one Bicep resource block in the other resource block?

This is the Bicep template to create Automation Account:

```
@description('Specifies the location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var accountname = 'Snapshot'
var runbookname = 'CreateSnapshot'
var schedulename = 'SnapshotHourly'


resource autaccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2021-06-22' = {
  name: accountname
  location: location
  tags: {
    test: 'true'
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    disableLocalAuth: false
    encryption: {
      identity: {
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Automation'
    }
    publicNetworkAccess: false
    sku: {
      capacity: null
      family: null
      name: 'Basic'
    }
  }
}

resource runbook1 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks@2019-06-01' = {
  parent: autaccount
  name: runbookname
  location: location
  properties: {
    runbookType: 'PowerShell'
    logVerbose: false
    logProgress: false
    logActivityTrace: 0
    publishContentLink: {
      uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/................'
    }
  }
}

resource schedule1 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/schedules@2020-01-13-preview' = {
  parent: autaccount
  name: schedulename
  properties: {
    startTime: '23:30'
    expiryTime: ''
    interval: 1
    frequency: 'Hour'
    timeZone: 'Europe/Riga'
  }
}

resource link 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/jobSchedules@2020-01-13-preview' = {
  name: guid('xxx05')
  parent: autaccount
  dependsOn: [
    runbook1
  ]
  properties: {
    parameters: {}
    runbook: {
      name: runbookname
    }
    schedule: {
      name: schedulename
    }
  }
}

output AutAccountPrincipalId string = autaccount.identity.principalId
```

The last resource block which actually assigns the Azure Role to MI is as follows:

```
@description('The principal to assign the role to')
param principalId string = 'abc897c3-ac9a-42e6-bc3f-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

@description('Built-in role to assign')
@allowed([
  'Owner'
  'Contributor'
  'Reader'
])
//param builtInRoleType string = 'Owner'

@description('A new GUID used to identify the role assignment')
param roleNameGuid string = newGuid()

var Owner = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635'
//var Contributor = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c'
//var Reader = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7'

resource roleassignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  name: roleNameGuid
  properties: {
    principalId: principalId
    roleDefinitionId: Owner
  }
}
```

I acquired the principalID value manually from Portal but to automate the thing need it to pass from the blocks above, from output above or by some other way. Can someone assist with that?
Thank you in advance!

The updated code is:

```
@description('Specifies the location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var accountname = 'SnapshotMgmtv11'
var runbookname = 'Create11'
var schedulename = 'SnapshotHourly11'


resource autaccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2021-06-22' = {
  name: accountname
  location: location
  tags: {
    test: 'true'
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    disableLocalAuth: false
    encryption: {
      identity: {
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Automation'
    }
    publicNetworkAccess: false
    sku: {
      capacity: null
      family: null
      name: 'Basic'
    }
  }
}

resource runbook1 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks@2019-06-01' = {
  parent: autaccount
  name: runbookname
  location: location
  properties: {
    runbookType: 'PowerShell'
    logVerbose: false
    logProgress: false
    logActivityTrace: 0
    publishContentLink: {
      uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/..................'
    }
  }
}

resource schedule1 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/schedules@2020-01-13-preview' = {
  parent: autaccount
  name: schedulename
  properties: {
    startTime: '08:30'
    expiryTime: ''
    interval: 1
    frequency: 'Hour'
    timeZone: 'Europe/Riga'
  }
}

resource link 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/jobSchedules@2020-01-13-preview' = {
  name: guid('riniv011')
  parent: autaccount
  dependsOn: [
    runbook1
  ]
  properties: {
    parameters: {}
    runbook: {
      name: runbookname
    }
    schedule: {
      name: schedulename
    }
  }
}


@description('A new GUID used to identify the role assignment')
param roleNameGuid string = newGuid()

//var Owner = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635'
var Contributor = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c'
//var Reader = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7'

resource roleassignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  name: roleNameGuid
  dependsOn: [
    autaccount
  ]
  properties: {
    principalId: autaccount.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: Contributor
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are deploying role assignement for resource group scope then you can use the something like below:**

I tested it for creating only automation account and assigning the owner role at resource group for the system assigned identity of the automation account.

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
var accountname = 'Snapshot'
resource autaccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2021-06-22' = {
  name: accountname
  location: location
  tags: {
    test: 'true'
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    disableLocalAuth: false
    encryption: {
      identity: {
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Automation'
    }
    publicNetworkAccess: false
    sku: {
      capacity: null
      family: null
      name: 'Basic'
    }
  }
}
param roleNameGuid string = guid('Owner')

var Owner = '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635'

resource roleassignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  name: roleNameGuid
  properties: {
    principalId: autaccount.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: Owner
    principalType:'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

For the below error :

[image]

Please add the `principalType:'ServicePrincipal'` in the role assignment block , as I have updated in the above code.